# External JS with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a "wizard" that calls a java-script external file. This wizard changes around different measurements for a wheelchair depending on numbers inputted into text box's. It calls the java-script, the java-script picks out the right wheelchair and then displays it back into a description box in the html.

A small part of my html code:

```
<script src="mywebsite/PPwizardA.js" type="text/javascript"> 
<input id="os5" name="os5" onChange="javascript: wizard()" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9" size="3" tabindex="2" type="text" />
```

This works in Joomla and works outside of a website (as in sitting on my desktop as just html and js files) But it doesn't work in WordPress.

Does WordPress have a whole other way of calling functions like this?

Comment: No. JS is JS. Open your browser's debugger, open the NETWORK/RESOURCE tab and reload the page. look for 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely due to the relative path you've used to get the script.

If you're building a theme or plugin you should consider using this method to include your scripts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

-Ken